Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac | Flutter build failed, after adding dependency
This is a new, empty project with only the default code. I've attached screenshots of all relevant Gradle files and other version details.
When I add dependencies, such as shared_preferences and others, my project encounters errors.
This code working fine in web but android getting error. Same error for path_provider lib as well
I've tried multiple versions but haven't been able to resolve the issue. Could you please help me find a solution?
Here is Error

Settings.gradle

gradle-wrapper.properties



share_preference causing a lot prb recently. u may try "Hive" package

@JBJason Same error for path_provider as well so its related to some Gradle and sdk support issue

@JBJason Hive is a "No Choice", Hive is unsupported for two years now!

@Sanjayrajsinh Was this project an old one? Have you issue a flutter upgrade recently?

As I Mentioned this is new project with only demo code

check if you are using java 17.

The error is somehow related to the new Android Studio update. Checkout this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/156304
This answer can fix your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79095064/7369590

Finally it's working. But  I need to reinstall android studio and gradle then set gradle setting as per this answer.

@Sanjayrajsinh Unfortunately yes you should reinstall android studio. But this will solve almost every problem with the latest android studio update.

Did you tried running flutter doctor --android-licenses and accept all of them? that sometimes could cause issues if you didn't done that, also I found some other solutions to a similiar issue here: flutter error Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
Also I'm not sure if you're on windows using WSL but looks like its one of the situations that could also cause your issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291122/Cannot-query-the-value-of-this-provider-because-it-has-no-value-available-when-importing-the-Android-project

I already accept this but still facing same
